# Chatbot to guide you while taking a picture using your phone camera

Tags: python, camera, chat, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm new to `chatbots`, and would like to simply check if the photo taken by the camera is blurred or not, and if blurred to ask the user to retake the image.

How can I start in building such simple chatbot? Can I use Python for that?

I know it is a general question, but would like your guidance as I have been looking around for a while now with no clear approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Writing natural language AI seems kind of tricky so I would probably want to use a service such as AWS Lex

Comment: Yes, you can use python for that purpose, and it may be the best option because you're gonna need image processing libraries to identify when the image is blurred, and this is your main problem, because it is not an easy job.

Comment: What is the goal of the chat bot? can you please give an example of the flow? all the bot needs to do is replay with something along the lines of "Sorry the image is too blurry please take a new image" what is the language interface to interact with it? SMS? FB? SLACK?